# Let $G$ be a finite abelian group. Show that there is a Galois extension $K/\Bbb Q$ with $\text{Gal}(K/\Bbb Q) \cong G$.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

> Let $G$ be a finite abelian group. Show that there is a Galois extension $K/\Bbb Q$ with $\text{Gal}(K/\Bbb Q) \cong G$.

I have seen a proof using that for a ﬁxed positive integer $n$, there are inﬁnitely many prime numbers $p$ such that $p ≡ 1 \bmod n$.

But is there any easy way to prove this? Please reply

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a simple argument to that special case of Dirichlet theorem, and it is a corollary of the following elementary fact:

> Given $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ non constant, than the set of primes $q$ such that $f(x)$ has a linear factor in $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$ is infinite.

You can prove this along the same kind of argument of Euclid: list those elements, say $p_1,...,p_n$, then observe that the constant factor, that is, $f(0)$ is factorized just by these primes, so deduce that the expression $f((p_1\cdots p_n)^k)$ has the same $p_i$-valuation of $f(0)$ for $k$ large enough, so you get that $f((p_1...p_n)^k)$ is bounded with $k$ varying, so $f$ is constant, contradiction.

Now apply this to $\Phi_n(x)$, the $n$-th cyclotomic polynomial, plus the observation that if  $x-a\mid \Phi_n(x)$ in $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$ then $\mathrm{ord}_q(a)=n$ so $n\mid q-1$.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1250336/121097) for a clearer proof of the highlighted result.