# Special types of prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers

We know that there is infinitely many of prime by the proof of Euclidean.and we know also that there are infinitely many of primes in  arithmetic progression by the Dirichlet theorem

My question is, are there some special types of prime number that it has proven that there is infinitely many of them like the Fermat prime or the Sophie German prime or any other special types?

Comment: Does this general result count? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250302/infiniteness-of-set-of-primes-such-f-have-root-mod-p

Comment: No.the special types that I am talking about have a relation with the integer $\mathbb{N}$ not a special polynomial or over some special field

Comment: Does this count? There are infinitely many primes that divide Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Yes can you give me a link or article tool about them .is this the only types  that you know?

Comment: It's conjectured that there are infinitely many repunit primes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repunit

Comment: He's not interested in conjectured ones by the sounds of it. Also, see: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.1655.pdf , although I must admit, I don't know how useful it is in actually answering the question. But the title seems promising.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedlander–Iwaniec_theorem is worth a look. (Sorry, for some reason the hyphen curtails the link. Copy and paste the entire url will work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are infinitely many primes that divide Fibonacci numbers.

See for instance

- [Infinite primes via Fibonacci numbers](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2017/01/17/infinite-primes-via-fibonacci-numbers/)

and the original paper

- [Another proof of the infinite primes theorem](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2313710)

Answer (score 2):

1. Famous Dirichlet theorem: Let $\ a\ $ and $\ b\ $ be relatively prime natural numbers. Then, there are infinitely many primes $\ p\equiv a\mod b.$
2. Fascinating Friedlander–Iwaniec theorem: there are infinitely many primes $\ p=a^2+b^4\ $ where $\ a\ $ and $\ b\ $ are natural numbers.